# Нестандартная форма глагола МИНОВАТЬ

Tags: выбор-слов, фразеология

Цитата из Двенадцати стульев:

> Старухи, пригнувшись и не оборачиваясь на стоявший в углу на мытом паркете громкоговоритель, продолжали есть, надеясь, **что их минет чаша сия.**

Викисловарь подсказывает, что такая форма допустима. Хочется понять, как правильно будет это выражение:

- минет чаша сия
- минёт чаша сия

И в каких случаях употребление такой формы допустимо в принципе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Из словаря (две формы)**: [минуть | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

**МИНУТЬ,** мину, минёшь, минёт; минул, -ла, -ло; минувший; минув; **МИНУТЬ**, мину, минешь, минет; минул, -ла, -ло; минувший; минув;

У Резниченко:

Ударение минёт, минёшь является **старой нормой** (встречается у поэтов): Мимо их висков вихрастых, Возле их мальчишьих глаз Смерть в бою свистела часто И **минёт** ли в этот раз? (А. Твардовский)

Но: Да не **минет** нас чаша Чрезвычайного Часа (А. Вознесенский).